# Sharepoint 2013 /ScriptResource.axd?d= and /WebResource.axd? 404 not found

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-404, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Farm  with name

dev22 and I have created a site collection with this url `http://dev22/test/site1`

And I have added a rule on TMG to redirect the url `http://dev22/test/site1` to  `https://mydomaine/test/site1`

But the problem I get the error 404 for /ScriptResource.axd?d= and /WebResource.axd?
 because he search the resources on my root domaine

https://mydomaine.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=
instead 
https://mydomaine.com/test/site1/ScriptResource.axd?d=

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have link translation on. You can configure a rule to replace part of the url.

- go to your firewall policies.
- right click on the firewall policy.
- click properties.
- navigate to the link translation tab.
- click on configure

[image]

- Then you should see this dialog

[image: TMG rule configuration window]

- click add
- you will want to replace '/ScriptResource.axd' with '/test/site1/ScriptResource.axd'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but if I add this rules on the firewall, I will get the same error for root website.

because I have a SPFarm on http://mydomain.com/
and other SPfarm on `http://dev22/test/site1`

and i have done redirection with the firewall https://mydomain.com/test/site1 to dev22 sitecollection